# how to fnd top 5 salary in MySql without using limit

Tags: mysql

Below query is not working in MySql.

```
SELECT * /*This is the outer query part */
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N-1) = ( /* Subquery starts here */
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
FROM Employee Emp2
WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

help me out.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SET @n := 0;
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT salary, @n := @n + 1 AS t1 FROM Employee ORDER BY salary DESC)
  AS t
WHERE t1 <= 5
```

**[Working DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67dfbe/1)**

Comment: @ParagBhingre:- It is a counter to check the count of salary.

Comment: but after running your query it is giving me salary unknown in field lists.

Comment: okay i got the answer rahul but it is showing 1st 4 records not 5.

Comment: @ParagBhingre:- You can change `WHERE t1 <= 5`

Comment: @ParagBhingre:- Added a working example. Hope that helps :)

Comment: actually i was not executed @n=0 every time that is why error was coming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92943/discussion-between-parag-bhingre-and-rahul-tripathi).